# Is the following inequality true

Tags: inequality

Is the following inequality true:

$\sqrt{(w+x)^2+(y+z)^2}\leq \sqrt{w^2+y^2} + \sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ for all $w,x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$

I've tried several test values for $w,x,y,z$ and they seem to satisfy the relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a(w,y)$ and $b(x,z)$ are two vectors . Left side of inequality is $|a+b|$ , right is $|a|+|b|$ but $|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$  so $\sqrt{(w+x)^2+(y+z)^2}\leq \sqrt{w^2+y^2} + \sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ (becouse $a+b=(w+x,y+z)$) . 
It is not hard to prove more general inequality : $\sqrt{(a_1+...+a_n)^2+(b_1+...+b_n)^2}\leq \sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}+...+\sqrt{a_n^2+b_n^2}$

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, let $\alpha_1=w+yi$ and $\alpha_2=x+zi$. Then this is the triangle inequality for complex numbers,
$$
|\alpha_1+\alpha_2|\leq|\alpha_1|+|\alpha_2|.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The distance formula can help you here and you can easily prove it using it. Anyway another way of proving it is using the [Minkowski Inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Minkowski_Inequality):

$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_1^{p}\right)^{\frac 1p} + \left( \sum_{i=1}^n b_1^{p}\right)^{\frac 1p} \ge \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left(a_1 + b_1\right)^{p}\right)^{\frac 1p}$$

which holds for $p \ge 1$ and $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Just plug $p=2$ and you have your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x,y,z,w\in \Bbb R$. Write

$$(w + x)^2 + (y + z)^2 = (w^2 + y^2) + (x^2 + z^2) + 2(xw + yz).$$

Since

\begin{align}(xw + yz)^2 &= x^2w^2 + y^2z^2 + 2xyzw\\
&=(w^2 + y^2)(x^2 + z^2) -  (z^2w^2 + x^2y^2- 2xyzw)\\
&= (w^2 + y^2)(x^2 + z^2) - (zw - xy)^2\\
&\le (w^2 + y^2)(x^2 + z^2),
\end{align}

we have

\begin{align}(w + x)^2 + (y + z)^2 &\le (w^2 + y^2) + (x^2 + z^2) + 2(xw + yz)\\
& \le (w^2 + y^2) + (x^2 + z^2) + 2(w^2 + y^2)(x^2 + z^2)\\
& = \left(\sqrt{w^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}\right)^2.
\end{align}

Taking the square root,

$$\sqrt{(w + x)^2 + (y + z)^2} \le \sqrt{w^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}.$$